# How to get the project base directory in a multi-module Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

We have a multi-module Maven project, which looks like this:

```
parent-module
-> dao-module-1
-> dao-module-2
-> algorithms-module
-> jaxb-module
-> jaxrs-module
-> webapp-module
```

I have code in the algorithms-module which needs to write an image to the webapp-module. That way, the end-users can point their browsers to a URL in the webapp-module and retrieve the image.

Without hardcoding the path to the parent-module, what's the best way to get the path to the parent-module? Is there a default property in Maven which has this value? If not, would setting this property in the POM files be a good solution?

Comment: Can't you incliude algorithms-module as a dependency of webapp-module and access the code to write the image within webapp-module.

Comment: It sounds you design has a problem, cause if you need to go beyond the module boundaries you are doing something wrong.  Can you also describe more in detail what you mean by: `algorithms-module which needs to write an image to the webapp-module.` ? Are you talking about build time? Or runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use `./` at the beginning of the string path if you wan to keep everything relative.

Alternately, you could use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the absolute path to the parent project folder.